# TCP socket server in node js with persistent connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have created one socket server in node js where I can send some data and receive from the server, but the problem is every time connection is closing and creating new PID for another request. here my requirement is once my IOT device connects to the server then the connection should stay there and I want to send, receive data any time.
Can anyone help me out?
I am posting my code below

Server code

```
 var net = require('net');

// Create Server instance 
var server = net.createServer(main);  

server.listen(9010, function() {  
  console.log('server listening on %j', server.address());
});

function main(sock) { 
  sock.setEncoding("utf8");

  sock.on('data', function(data) {
    var data = data;
    console.log('Request data is ', data);
    console.log('Says:', data);
    sock.write("responding to client");
    sock.write(' exit');
  });

  sock.on('close',  function () {
    console.log('connection closed');
  });

  sock.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Connection error: %s', err.message);
  });
};
```

Client code

```
   var net = require('net');

    //params
    var HOST = 'myhost';
    var PORT = 9010;

    var client = new net.Socket();
    client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {

        console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
        client.write('Hello socket server');
    });

    client.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('Recieved data: ' + data);
        client.destroy();

    });
    // Add a 'close' event handler for the client socket
    client.on('close', function() {
        console.log('Connection closed');
    });
```

Comment: WebSockets are NOT raw TCP/IP sockets. The name "WebSocket" refers to [a specific protocol name](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455) (like HTTP refers to a specific protocol name). Please don't use the WebSocket tag unless your question relates to the protocol.

Comment: Why is `var HOST = 'myhost'`? Aren't you testing using `localhost` (same machine)?

Comment: var HOST = 'myhost'
Here i am using myhost where i hosted my socket server i.e socket.mydomain.com.